# Print takes more than 2 seconds in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, performance

I have a variable which is `obj=model.filter(id=id)` and i have **print function** which display obj value. i measure it by `pref_counter()` it takes more than 2 seconds.

my code are like

```
obj=model.filter(id=id)
c = time.perf_counter()
print(obj)
d = time.perf_counter()
print("seconds", d - c) #shows 2 seconds
```

Fun part is if I print it twice, it will take 4 seconds.

Comment: I guess it's not print taking too much, but `model.filter()` works so. on the first line there is no request for DB as it uses lazy requests. The request itself works only on the 3d line when you try to print it.

Comment: Can you add the model to the question? Printing a queryset will cause it to fetch the first few results and include them in the print, are you doing something complex or accessing related objects in the model's `__str__` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer is:**

As it was mentioned in comments by Sergey, It is not about print, when I call print  request itself works, and request takes more time.